# Count and display occurrences in 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

My code is dispalying the array fine. How to display the number of times the given integer is repeated and display the subscript locations where it is repeated?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int table [10][10]={{0},{0}};
    int repeat=0;
    int count=0;
    int r=0;
    int c=0;
    //seeding the random function
    srand(static_cast<int>(time(0)));

    for(r=0; r<10; r++)//row
    {
        for(c=0; c<10; c++)
        {
            table[r][c] = 50+rand() %(100-50+1);
            cout << table[r][c]<<"  ";

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Enter the number to know how many times it is repeated(50 to 100): ";
    cin>>repeat;
    for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
    {
        if(repeat==table[r][c])
            count+=1;

    }

    cout<<"the number "<<repeat<<" appeared"<<count<<" times."<<endl;
    //display new line

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: How to code to display the number of times the given integer is repeated and display the subscript locations where it is repeated?

Comment: Kind of, I am self learning from a book.

Comment: Mixing tabs and spaces for indentation is usually a problem; the best way to get consistent results with all tools (including ones you might not think of at first, such as SO) is to make your editor insert spaces when you press the tab key.  (I reformatted the code for you here.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your counting code iterating over the matrix. 'x' is not mentioned anywhere in 'for' loop.

Comment: oh yeah. now it is displaying the number of times. Thank you.

Comment: Please tell me how display the subscript locations.

Answer (score 0):

You should to replace your code:

```
for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
{
    if(repeat==table[r][c])
        count+=1;
}
```

to this:

```
for (r = 0; r < 10; r ++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < 10; c ++)
    {
        if(table[r][c] == repeat)    // checking
             count ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: ye I did that and it is displaying the number of times. I have no clue to how to display the subscript location where the number is repeated.

Comment: Please help display the subscript locations where it is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

You can display subscript locations in the for loop:

```
puts ("Locations:");
for (r = 0; r < 10; r ++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < 10; c ++)
    {
        if(table [r][c] == repeat)            // checking
        {
            printf ("[%i, %i]\n", r, c);      // display where it is
            count ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can create a special array of encountered subscripts:

```
int rs [100];    // rows and columns indexes of repeated subscripts
int cs [100];    //

for (r = 0; r < 10; r ++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < 10; c ++)
    {
        if(table [r][c] == repeat)            // checking
        {
            // no printf code here
            rs [count] = r;
            cs [count] = c;
            count ++;
        }
    }
}

// subscripts can be displayed or used in math algorithm now:

puts ("Locations:");
for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++)
    printf ("[%i, %i]", rs [i], cs [i]);
```

The last method isn't optimal, but it's suitable for learning C ;) Have a good coding!